Dataweave Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor
Input: "Wed, 27 Mar 2024 07:46:33"
code:
payload as DateTime{format: "E, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"}

Error:
Cannot coerce String (Wed, 27 Mar 2024 07:46:33) to DateTime, caused by: Text 'Wed, 27 Mar 2024 07:46:33' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=27, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2024, DayOfWeek=3, MonthOfYear=3},ISO resolved to 07:46:33 of type java.time.format.Parsed

5|     updatedTime: payload.ENDTIME 
...
    as DateTime{format: "E, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"}

Trace:
  at main::main (line: 5, column: 18)

Can someone help me what changes i need to make here

Since Timezone is not present you can convert it to LocalDateTime
Note-> year should be yyyy not YYYY DateTime CookBook
payload as LocalDateTime {format: "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"}


as LocalDateTime {format: "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
as LocalDateTime
This one worked for me..
